# Faster way to replace strings in pandas series using dictionary in Python

Tags: python, strings, pandas

I'm working with a dictionary with 11830 keys/values, that have to loop over 13905 strings, that can have up to 50 words each. My series looks like this:

```
  strings
"hello foo helloo"
"bye bar byer"
```

And my dictionary like this:

```
dic={'hello':'hi','bye':'byebye'}
```

So I want my final `Series` to look like this:

```
  strings
"hi foo helloo"
"byebye bar byer"
```

I achieved that like this:

```
for k,v in dicc.items():
    b=b.apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'\b'+k+r'\b',r'\b'+v+r'\b',x))
```

But it's quite slow. Is there a faster way to do it?

Edit: noticed splitting the string didn't solve the issue of replacing substrings that matched the dictionary.